# Seg Fault while strcpy

Tags: c

This is the relevant piece of code I'm working on. I tokenize an input from the stdin with no issue and when I go to copy that input, I'm getting a segfault. However, I get no segfault with "strcpy(s,input)". Am I missing something fundamental here? Thank you

```
char *s = malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
char *token = malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
char *currstring = malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
currstring = NULL;
fgets(input,100, stdin);
strcpy(s, input);
token = strtok(s,delim);

while (token) 
{
    //Condition checking      
     strcpy(currstring,token);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
char *currstring = malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
currstring = NULL;
```

You allocate memory, but then you immediately discard it and set the pointer to NULL. Get rid of the second line.

If you were trying to set it to an empty string (`""`), instead do:

```
currstring[0] = '\0';
// or
strcpy(currstring, "");
```

This probably isn't necessary, though. You don't need to set the string to `""` if you're going to do a `strcpy()` later.

```
char *token = malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
```

You also do not need to allocate memory for `token`. `strtok()` will cause `token` to point somewhere within `s`, so allocating memory for `token` will simply leak memory once you do `token = strtok(s, delim);`.

Comment: OP is also reading up to 100 characters into `input` (whose definition is not shown), but then copying the contents into `s`, which contains only 64 bytes.